# Xamarin forms Hybridweb view mailto link not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I have implemented a hybrid webview in my xamarin forms pcl project. I have a html page in which I have created a mailto link but it is not working on clicking it, it shows no webpage found.

In uwp, it asks for opening app.

Hybridwebview

```
public class HybridWebView : View
    {
        Action<string> action;

        public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Uri",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Uri
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
        }

        public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
        {
            action = callback;
        }

        public void Cleanup()
        {
            action = null;
        }

        public void InvokeAction(string data)
        {
            if (action == null || data == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            action.Invoke(data);
        }
    }
```

Renderer in Droid-

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
    {
       const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";
       const string downloadFunction = "function downloadbook(data){jsBridge.invokeDownloadAction(data);}";

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;              
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
                //string url = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), Element.Uri);
                //Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file://{0}", url));

                Task.Run(() => {
                    Task.WaitAny(Task.Delay(2000));
                    InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);
                    CallJS();
                });

            }
        }

        void InjectJS(string script)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {                  
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("Javascript: {0}", script));
            }
        }

        void CallJS()
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should subscribe to the `OnNavigating` event of the `WebView` and handle mailto links there.

```
void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.StartsWith ("mailto")) {
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(e.Url););
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

It's important to cancel the navigation since you're moving out of the app and there's no need for the WebView to try navigate any further.

Comment: There is no on navigating event in hybrid web view

Comment: @Sonali, subscribe the [Navigating Event](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.WebView.Navigating/) of the `WebView`.

Comment: @Grace Feng - MSFT how? Actually I am new to xamarin. So where I can subscribe this event?

Comment: @Sonali, for example, if your `WebView` is named `webview`, then `webview.Navigating+=OnNavigating`, then try hankide's code.

Comment: @Grace Feng Mine webview is hybrid. I added code this time.

Comment: @Sonali, It's too long to comment here, I just wrote an answer, you can have a check.

Answer (score 0):

> Mine webview is hybrid. I added code this time.

I found your problem, since your `HybridWebView` inherits from `View`, not [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.WebView/) of Xamainr Forms, you cannot subscribe the event of `WebView`. One method to solve your issue is that you can modify your `HybridWebView` class to inherit from `WebView`:

```
public class HybridWebView : WebView
```

If you use this method, then the `Control` in your `HybridWebViewRenderer` refers to the `Android.Webkit.WebView`, you don't need to create a new one.

The `Navigating` event should be subscribed in PCL, but if you want to do this work in your Android project, you can also implement your own [WebViewClient](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Webkit.WebViewClient/) and override the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` event.